# Timer output save

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timer

I made a script that counts the time, what I want is:

- Save the time somewhere, like on a different or the same page.
  What is the best way to do this? Should I get into mysql and php to do this?
  And how should I this in mysql-php etc.
  Or is there an easier way, like writeLN on the same page.

edit: script is

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var c=58;
    var minutes= 1;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on=0;

    function timedCount()
    {
      document.getElementById("txtSec").value=c;
      document.getElementById('txtMin').value=minutes;
      c=c+1;
      if (c%60==0){
        minutes+=1;
        c=0;
      }
      t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
    }

    function doTimer()
    {
      if (!timer_is_on)
      {
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
      }
    }

    function stopCount()
    {
      clearTimeout(t);
      timer_is_on=0;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  Seconds:<input type="text" id="txtSec"><br>
  Minutes:<input type="text" id="txtMin"><br>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="doTimer()">
<button onclick="stopCount()">Stop count!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you need the value to persist, for how long does it need to persist, and does it need to persist throughout a user session?

Comment: I need to store the value for myself only, I need to store it forever.

Comment: if you need to store value forever then save it in database

Comment: Abdul, can you give me a hint or a direction on how to do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this pure client side, consider the new persistent storage features in HTML5. It's not going to be completely cross browser, but for the most part you should be ok if this is just for you, and you're always on the same machine. It's just a matter of grabbing a handle to the filesystem sandbox, and then reading/writing data to the stream and closing it.

The concept is very similar to how Java handles this. You get a handle which represents a stream interface to the filesystem, you write data to that stream, flush it out, and close the stream. That will persist the value in your browser for you to pull out by essentially doing the reverse. You open a stream reader, read in the data, and do what you will with it.
Here are some [api docs to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System)

Comment: Too bad I need to have access to it on several computers and devices.

Comment: How often does it change? Have you considered just taking the result and writing it down somewhere? At this point I'm honestly confused as to why on earth you'd want to do this.

Comment: Daily, I can't write it down every time, because some people have to see my progress.

Comment: If you need to use it across multiple devices and it changes frequency, then you'll need some rudimentary PHP (or really any server side language) and some sort of database to store it in. I recommend PHP/MySQL for this as it's the most simple way IMHO (and best way! ;)   ) Doesn't have to be any thing complicated. Read up on PHP and MySQL and how to connect the two and try from that. If you run into issues, let us know.